# Concat arrays at a certain index with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation

I want to do this in LINQ:

```
public static void ConcatAt(this string[] items, string[] others, int at)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < others.Length && at < items.Length; i++, at++) {
        items[at] = others[i];
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
string[] groups = { "G1", "G2", "G3" };
string[] names = new string[groups.Length + 1];
names[0] = "Choose";
names.ConcatAt(groups, 1);

foreach (var n in names)
    Console.WriteLine(n);

/*
Choose
G1
G2
G3
*/
```

String was just an example, could be anything though.

So is there a LINQ method that does this?

Doing a `names = names.Concat(groups).ToArray();` will include the empty strings that's in names so if I print `names` I'd get:

```
/*
Choose



G1
G2
G3
*/
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand why, in your specific example, you can't use `names = names.Concat(groups).ToArray();`? Is the index a requirement .. ?

Comment: No because that would include the empty strings as well that's in names. So If I print `names`, I would get "Choose", "", "", "", G1", etc.

Comment: @vexe I don't know, it seems like a viable question to me. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you not using Array.Copy?

```
Array.Copy(groups, 0, names, at,groups.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I never used that. I thought there'd be some LINQ method.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work for you

```
         string[] groups = { "G1", "G2", "G3" };

        var myNewItems = groups.ToList();

        int pos = 1;
        string value = "Choose";
        myNewItems.Insert(pos,value);



        foreach (var v in myNewItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: specific means? do you want to combine array in diffrent datata types?

Comment: I mean, I was looking for a more general solution that concatenates arrays from a certain index within a certain length but you provided a work-around that works specifically for my case where I just have to insert "Choose" before the "G"s. Thanks for the help.